# Regex Negative Lookahead issue Ensure no repeating characters only in first group

Tags: regex

I'm attempting to write a regex with negative lookahead and seem to be having what looks like a minor syntax problem.

I want to match the following format:
DayOfWeek-24HourTimeFormat-Number[1-99]

Examples:
MTWRFSU-23:00-02
M-23:00-02
MT-23:00-02

I don't want the Day of week (before first hyphen) to have any repeat letters, and can only be one of the following: MTWRFSU

The following regex is only matching the last letter of my examples

```
((?!=.*(.).*\1)[MTWRF])-([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]-([1-9]|[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])
```

For Example MT-23:00-2 is only matching T-23:00-2

This is probably something simple. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing or if there is a better way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

```
((?!=.*(.).*\1)[MTWRF])-([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]-([1-9]|[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])
```

I'm expecting
MT-23:00-02 (MATCH)
MTT-23:00-02 (FAIL, because T is repeated)

Comment: What language are you using? This will influence the answers that you get

Comment: `^(?![A-Z]*([MTWRFSU])[A-Z]*\1)([MTWRFSU]+)-([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]-(0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])$`, see https://regex101.com/r/jpkJSL/1

Comment: Why not ^M?T?W?R?F?S?U? at the beginning of the phrase?

Comment: @SlawomirDziuba - Can't use that because it want's to control the order of appearance, which can be random..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `(?!=.*(.).*\1)` lookahead will fail to match strings where you have *any* repeating char, even the hyphen or space.

You need to use something like

```
^(?![A-Z]*([MTWRFSU])[A-Z]*\1)([MTWRFSU]+)-([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]-(0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jpkJSL/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![A-Z]*([MTWRFSU])[A-Z]*\1)` - no repeated `M`, `T`, `W`, `R`, `F`, `S`, `U` separated with 0 or more uppercase letters and only after 0 or more of such letters
- `([MTWRFSU]+)` - Group 1: `M`, `T`, `W`, `R`, `F`, `S` or `U`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])` - Group 2: `0` or `1` optionally and then any digit or `20` to `23`
- `:` - a colon
- `[0-5][0-9]` - `00` to `59`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])` - Group 3: optional `0` and then a digit from `1` to `9` or `10` to `99`.
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I needed. I'm planning to use this with regularexpression validator control in .NET. I used your regex demo link and this looks great!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the fastest way to do it is like this.
Here, just focusing in on the letters part.

`(?m)^(?:(?>(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)([MTWRFSU])|(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)([MTWRFSU])|(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)([MTWRFSU])|(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)([MTWRFSU])|(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)([MTWRFSU])|(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)([MTWRFSU])|(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)([MTWRFSU]))){1,7}$`

https://regex101.com/r/gBaBYw/1

Expanded

```
 (?m)    
 ^ 
 (?:   
    (?>
        (?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)( [MTWRFSU] )
      | (?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)( [MTWRFSU] )
      | (?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)( [MTWRFSU] )
      | (?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)( [MTWRFSU] )
      | (?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)( [MTWRFSU] )
      | (?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)( [MTWRFSU] )
      | (?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)( [MTWRFSU] )
    )
 ){1,7}
 $
```

We can compare the regex presented on this page through a benchmark,
where this regex is #1, Stribnetz improved regex is #2 and Stribnetz
original regex is #3.

Usually, in these kind of regex, the speedier the better !

```
Regex1:   (?m)^(?:(?>(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)([MTWRFSU])|(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)([MTWRFSU])|(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)([MTWRFSU])|(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)([MTWRFSU])|(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)([MTWRFSU])|(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)([MTWRFSU])|(?!\1|\2|\3|\4|\5|\6)([MTWRFSU]))){1,7}$
Completed iterations:   5  /  5     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   9
Elapsed Time:    0.63 s,   627.27 ms,   627275 µs
Matches per sec:   71,738


Regex2:   (?m)^(?![MTWRFSU]*([MTWRFSU])[MTWRFSU]*\1)[MTWRFSU]+$
Completed iterations:   5  /  5     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   9
Elapsed Time:    0.66 s,   664.90 ms,   664896 µs
Matches per sec:   67,679


Regex3:   (?m)^(?![A-Z]*([MTWRFSU])[A-Z]*\1)[MTWRFSU]+$
Completed iterations:   5  /  5     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   9
Elapsed Time:    0.84 s,   837.94 ms,   837943 µs
Matches per sec:   53,702
```